# How can I trim a tensor based on a mask with PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor `inp`, which has a size of: `torch.Size([4, 122, 161])`.

I also have a `mask` with a size of: `torch.Size([4, 122])`.

Each element in my `mask` looks something like:

```
tensor([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
```

So I want to trim `inp` to be reduced along the dimension=1 to only exist where the `mask` has `1`. In the case shown, there are 23 `1`s, so I want the size of `inp` to be: `torch.Size([4, 23, 161])`

Comment: Does `mask` have the same number of 1s in each of the 4 masks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think advanced indexing would work. (I assume every mask has equally 23 1s)

```
inp_trimmed = inp[mask.type(torch.bool)].reshape(4,23,161)
```